# View an XML file in Tree View using appJar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a GUI using appJar(python Library, uses Tkinter). I have an XML file.
I am parsing the XML file using ElementTree XML parsing library.

I want to see my XML file in a tree view.
So I am parsing the file using Element Tree, Getting the tags in Need to show in the Treeview and Forming a new XML object. and passing the new object in the appJar Function: .addTree().
But I am Getting the error as:

```
..lib\site-packages\appJar\appjar.py", line 8764, in addTree
    xmlDoc = parseString(data).

...lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'ElementTree'
```

---

```
xml=et.Element(root)
print(xml)
for ele in valList:
    reg=et.SubElement(xml, ele.find('Name').text)
    bitroot= ele.findall('Bit')
    for bit in bitroot:
        et.SubElement(reg, bit.find('Name').text)

xmltree= et.ElementTree(xml)
app.startFrame('bottomleft',1,0,2)
app.setBg('orange')
app.setSticky('news')
app.setStretch('none')
app.addTree('REGISTER', xmltree)
```

> I am getting the error, as far as I can understand is because .addTree() API is unable to read the format of xmltree variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [appJar documentation](http://appjar.info/pythonDevWidgets/#tree), you need to pass an XML string to `.addTree()`, not an `ElementTree`. According to [ElementTree documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), you can use `xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring()` to build an XML string from your `Element`:

```
xml_string = et.tostring(xml)
app.addTree('REGISTER', xml_string)
```